# Create a user defined library in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a eclipse plugin project which automatically add an user defined libary to the workspace(e.g. - ApachePOI which includes some .jar file of my choice). I am trying to find the answer for a day, but could not find any hint.

I know how to do it manually

`Windows-> preferences -> User Libraries -> create new -> add jars` .

In other words, I have a user library in my currenct plugin development workspace. I need to user that same user library in my target platform.

Create new eclipse plugin project -> run as Eclipse Application -> the result workspace will have a user defined library there.

Is there any way I can do it?

Any idea how I should proceed for this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Things in the target platform must be plugins not plain jars.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks!. The scenario is that, I need to add a couple of jar automatically added to the target platform so that every projects the user creates in the target platform can access those jars directly without importing the jar individually in the projects in the target platform. Is that even feasible ?

Comment: No. As I said everything in the target platform **must** be a plugin. You would have to package these jars as plugins and use the usual Require-Bundle or Import-Package mechanisms to access them.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I will try.

Comment: @greg-449 , Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to create a plugin with all my needed jars and created a plugin. I have this plugin at my workspace. Then I used this in my project. But, unfortunately, it is giving "type not accessible due to restriction" error while running. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you export the packages in the plugin ('Export-Package') in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: @greg-449, Thanks. I didn't do that previously. I am doing it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449. At least now my plugin can recognize Apache poi jars at the target platform. Thanks again!